# Android UI omits some updates

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I am dealing with the android UI and I am facing what looks a very common problem here. **By using an AsyncTask, I want to:**

1- Show a ProgressDialog meanwhile some stuff gets ready

2- Show a countdown to let the user get ready for the real action

3- Play a sound afterwards the countdown to notify the sample will be taken

4- Show another ProgressDialog representing the 10s sample taking

5- Play a sound afterwards the sample is taken

**Well, this is my outcome:**

1- Works fine

2- MISSING, THE UI IS NOT UPDATED BUT THE BACKGROUND PROCESS IS RUNNING

3- Works fine

4- Works fine

5- Works fine

The funniest is, when I remove the code to handle the first part that handles the first progress dialog, the other parts are executed/displayed as expected. I understand there is something blocking the UI at some point but I am quite newbie with android to realize what's blocking it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
public class SnapshotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int COUNTDOWN_TIME = 5;
    private Button startStop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_snapshot);
        startStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartStop);
        startStop.setText("START");
    }

    public void startSnapshot(View view) {
        startStop.setClickable(false);
        new Async(SnapshotActivity.this).execute();
    }

    class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCountDown);
            ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
            ProgressDialog preparing;
            Context context;

            int flag = 0;
            int counter = COUNTDOWN_TIME;

            public Async(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                preparing = new ProgressDialog(context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                //PROGRESS DIALOG
                flag = 4;
                publishProgress();
                try {

                    //SIMULATE SOME WORKLOAD
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                flag = 5;
                publishProgress();

                //HANDLE THE COUNTDOWN
                for(counter = COUNTDOWN_TIME; counter>=1; counter--){
                    publishProgress();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }

                //PLAY THE SOUND
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                        r.play();
                    }
                }).start();

                //PROGRESS DIALOG
                flag = 1;
                publishProgress();

                //10s SAMPLE
                flag = 2;
                for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j++ ){

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    publishProgress();
                }

                //PLAY THE SOUND
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                        r.play();
                    }
                }).start();

                flag = 3;
                publishProgress();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                switch (flag) {
                    case 0:
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        tv.setText("");
                        progressDialog.setTitle("TAIKING SAMPLE");
                        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                        progressDialog.setMax(10);
                        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progressDialog.show();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        preparing.setMessage("Starting the device...");
                        preparing.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        preparing.show();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        preparing.dismiss();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                startStop.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: are you creating the task instance and calling `execute()` on the main thread?

Comment: @nandsito yes, I do: `new Async(SnapshotActivity.this).execute();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

- You are not informing `onProgressUpdate()` of the countdown value
- There is a race condition

`doInBackground()` and `onProgressUpdate()` methods are executed in two different threads and both methods/threads are accessing the `flag` field in a unsafe way. Instead of setting a value in `flag` in `doInBackground()` to be read in `onProgressUpdate()`, you can inform this value directly in the `publishProgress()` call. So I advise you to do the following:

```java
public class SnapshotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    // Change the Progress generic type to Integer.
    class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        // Remove the flag field.
        // int flag = 0;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //PROGRESS DIALOG
            // Pass the flag argument in publishProgress() instead.
            // flag = 4;
            publishProgress(4);

            // ...

            // flag = 5;
            publishProgress(5);

            //HANDLE THE COUNTDOWN
            for (counter = COUNTDOWN_TIME; counter>=1; counter--){

                // The countdown progress has two parameters:
                // a flag indicating countdown and
                // the countdown value.
                publishProgress(6, counter);

                // ...
            }

            //PLAY THE SOUND

            // ...

            //PROGRESS DIALOG
            // flag = 1;
            publishProgress(1);

            //10s SAMPLE
            // flag = 2;
            for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j++ ){

                // ...

                publishProgress(2);
            }

            //PLAY THE SOUND

            // ...

            // flag = 3;
            publishProgress(3);

            return null;
        }

        // This signature changes.
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            // Redeclare flag here.
            int flag = values[0];

            switch (flag) {

                // ...

                case 6:
                    tv.setText(Integer.toString(values[1]));
                    break;

                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```